# Magento 2: I need to get Current quote data from checkout cart model in Custom cron job

Tags: magento2, cron

I want to get current quote data for cronjob in cron/run.php. But it's not working.

Please check my below code. I am stuck with this. `Magento2 version is CE 2.2.6`

```
namespace ABC\Abandon\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Run {

    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

    }

    public function execute(){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $quoteId = $cartObj->getQuote()->getId();
        $itemsArray = $cartObj->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($itemsArray as $item) {
            $productName[] = $item->getName();
        }
        if(is_array($productName)){
            $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
        }
        $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
        $abdata['quoteid'] = $quoteId;
        return $abdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the "current quote" be in cron context? Usually a user has a session and when something is added to cart a quote is created and assigned to that session (i.e. the quote id is kept in the session) - whitout such session data there is no "current quote".

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution:

```
<?php
namespace ABC\Abandon\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Run {

    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $quoteItemCollectionFactory;
    protected $_quotesFactory;
    protected $_storeManager; 
    protected $queryResolver;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QueryResolver $queryResolver,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $quoteItemCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quotesFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory = $quoteItemCollectionFactory;
        $this->queryResolver = $queryResolver;
        $this->_quotesFactory = $quotesFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    }

    public function execute(){
        $abandonCartCollection = $this->_quotesFactory->create();
        $abandonCartCollection->prepareForAbandonedReport($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $abandondata = [];
        $productNames = $abandonCartId ='';
        $status ='';
        $productName=array();
        $productImage=array();
        $abandonCartId = $abandonCart->getEntity_id();
        $abandondata['quoteid'] = $abandonCartId;
        $abandondata['emailAddress'] = $abandonCart->getCustomer_email(); //pankaj.s23234@grazitti.com
        $itemCollection = $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory->create();
        $itemCollection->prepareActiveCartItems();
        $itemCollection->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', array('eq'=>$abandonCartId));
        if (count($itemCollection)) {
            foreach($itemCollection as $item)
        {
            $productName[] = $item->getName();
        }
        if(is_array($productName)){
            $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
        }
        $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
        $abdata['quoteid'] = $quoteId;

        }
        return $abdata;
    }
}
```