# Magento 2: I need to run observer in crontab.xml. But it is not working

Tags: cron, magento2.3, crontab

I am running observer in crontab.xml. This is not working.

Here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default"> 
        <job name="abandon_cron_run" instance="Abc\Abandon\Observer\Abandon" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule> 
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Abandon.php

```
namespace Abc\Abandon\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Abandon  implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

    )
    {
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

            $productName=array();
            $productNames=''; 
             $itemsArray = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getItems();
            foreach($itemsArray as $item) {
                $productName[] = $item->getName();
            }
                 if(is_array($productName)){
                    $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
                } 

                $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
            return $abdata; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: I need to get Current quote data from checkout cart model in Custom cron job](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268919/magento-2-i-need-to-get-current-quote-data-from-checkout-cart-model-in-custom-c)

Comment: the problem is on `$observer->getCart()` , and put some log to check it is executing or not

Comment: Yes it is working.

Comment: @Shiwani You can not trigger observer file directly through cron because you will not get data in observer file(i.e $observer variable will not have data) which you are wanting to access. id suggest you create a custom event settiing the data and then recalling that from within your cron job. this should give you the result you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you are trying to achieve in your model, but as Dava suggests you won't be getting an observer passed into your method. You should change your model to something like:

```
namespace Abc\Abandon\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Abandon  implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

If you want to confirm it is running you could do something like:

```
namespace Abc\Abandon\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Abandon  implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);
    }
}
```