# Magento 2: Cron is not working

Tags: magento2

I have added the cronetab.xml like below.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="customdesignsubcategories_cron">
      <job name="uploadFile_deletion" instance="KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron\Test" method="execute">
          <schedule>*/2 * * * *</schedule>
      </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

and also created the class in Directory like Vendor/Module/Crone like below but I could not check my cron is worked or not.

```
<?php

namespace KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron;

class Test
{
  protected $_logger;
  public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) 
  {
      $this->_logger = $logger;
  }
  public function execute()
  {
      $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/system.log');
      $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
      $logger->addWriter($writer);
      $logger->info('Your text message');
      exit;
  }
}
```

Above Message is not display in **system.log** file.

Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please refer this link 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268919/magento-2-i-need-to-get-current-quote-data-from-checkout-cart-model-in-custom-c

Comment: Ensure that your file name `cronetab.xml` is wrong.it should be `crontab.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below things

1. Check the cron service running by the command `sudo service cron status`.
   If it is not running, then please start the service `sudo service cron start`
2. Install [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) and run your custom cron by job name `php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run uploadFile_deletion`, it throws an error detail if you made any mistakes with the code. In this way, you can easily identify the issue.